# What is Source Density of an Icon :: A setting showed in Android Asset Studio?

Tags: android, nine-patch

### I am trying to generate a 9-patch drawable icon

---

- I am using the [**ANDROID-ASSET-STUDIO**](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) for this !
- My image Dimention :: `85*39`

---

When i tried to use [**this**](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html) ....

1. There is a setting which says ***`Source Density`*** ..... What is
   it    ?
2. How can i know the source density for my image ?

**Snapshot**::

[image]